# What is the best data structure to store cities and states in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures

In my C# program, I plan to query my database for cities and states, and I want to store the information in some sort of list so that I can run a foreach loop.
I considered a hash table at first, but I'm not sure that would work since there can be multiple identical keys (cities with the same name). Is there a data structure that can store pairs (city, state) or does the C# ArrayList allow some sort of mapping? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need that sort of mapping in a class? You can have a collection of states and a collection of cities. A state can have a collection of cities and/or a city can have a state.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you can use 2 data structures for this, such like:

```
Dictionary<State, List<City>> yourObject
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: You could simplify this to Dictionary<string, List<string>> if you just want to store the names.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a tuple with two elements like this:

```
var city = new Tuple<string, string>("New York", "NY");
```

Then just create a standard list containing all the tuples, then you will be able to do a for each loop on it. To access the city name you can just do `city.Item1` and to access the state `city.Item2`.